# Can't get --supported-products option to work with Amazon's elastic-mapreduce Ruby client for Karmasphere Analytics

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

I am trying to use Karmaspere Analytics with AWS. [This](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?UsingEMR_Karmasphere.html) page says to use --supported-products with the ruby client. However, when I run the command (exactly as entered on that page), I get an error "Error: invalid option: --supported-products"

I am using Version 2010-11-11, downloaded from http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2264 (that page says it was last updated on Aug 11, 2011, but running ./elastic-mapreduce --version I get "Version 2010-11-11" as output)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is mistake in documentation. Its `--with-supported-products`. If you run ruby client without any arguments you will see the correct options to use.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for bringing this documentation error to light. The fix is, as Pratik indicated, to use --with-supported-products. I've updated the Amazon Elastic MapReduce documentation to reflect this: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_Karmasphere.html